# Валидация полей в модальном окне

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

В моделе есть правила

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['decision_category_id', 'comments', 'huskies_fb', 'other_huskies', 'raiting'], 'integer'],
        [['articles_name', 'source'], 'required'],
        [['source'], 'url', 'defaultScheme' => 'http'],
        [['favicon'], 'string'],
        [['publication_date', 'update_date_of_huskies_comments_views', 'created', 'updated'], 'safe'],
        [['favorites_ar', 'selected_kk', 'tags', 'author', 'note', 'images', 'views', 'translation', 'original', 'other_sources', 'selected_km_and_polina'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['source'], 'string', 'max' => 1000],
        [['description'], 'string', 'max' => 10000],
    ];
}
```

отображаю форму в модальном окне через `return $this->renderAjax()`
если заполнять `note` корректно, то есть не более 255 символов, то два обязательных поля валидируются нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а если превысить более 255 символов и нажать "Добавить", то вот что
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
помогите разобраться =)

Comment: а в чём проблема? если нужно больше 255 символов убрать из правил это поле и добавить в safe

Comment: дело в том, что запрещено в бд записывать в это поле более 255 символов, по опр, причинам

Comment: поменяйте тип в бд для этого поля longtext для примера

Comment: Не очевидное решение нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404481/yii2-bootstrap-modal-form-validation-ajax-any-insight-on-strange-behavior/29462393#29462393).